# Can Drupal store content into XML?

Tags: xml, drupal, content-management-system

I am looking for a good CMS, like Drupal... But we must store content into XML datatype (with PostgreSQL 9.X that have good support to XML).

The articles (CMS content) are richly formatted, with XHTML5 and [Microformat or RDFa standards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RDFa). So, if each article of CMS's database can be stored with [XML datatype](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/datatype-xml.html),  we can use [XPath to query](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/functions-xml.html) the article's information fragments. 
PS: we will use the CMS (Drupal) only to organization and maintenance or little updates in the articles, will not for authors/copywriters create new articles.

Can I addapt Drupal for this task? There are a fork, plugin or discussion about it?

Answer (score 2):

Out of the box, Drupal store its data in SQL, with support for both MySQL and PostgreSQL. Drupal 7 and 8 provide an high [level data storage model](https://www.drupal.org/node/1261744) and [API](https://www.drupal.org/developing/api/entity/7). Contents, and other type of data, are entities with fields. Entities and their fields are stored using an pluggable storage engine. In theory, you can write your storage engine to store entities using in XML datatype in PostgreSQL. For instance, there is a [MongoDB field storage](https://www.drupal.org/project/mongodb) for Drupal 7 that store fields in a MongoDB database.

The Entity API and its storage part have been heavily re-architectured in Drupal 8, given the amount of work needed to write your own storage engine, it may be a better option to plan on using Drupal 8.

Comment: Thanks Pierre, good clues!  Do you have a link to the Drupal-8 data model with the "content fields"? I not [see here](https://www.drupal.org/files/Drupal8_UPsitesWeb_Schema_10-19-2013.png) where  Drupal store its contents in SQL. Im my opinion what I need is very simple, is only to change a `text` SQL datatype field to `xml` datatype field -- and (no so "only") review all the impact, doing a lot of casts like `field::text`.

Comment: ops, [here a old (2013) Drual8](https://www.drupal.org/files/Drupal8_UPsitesWeb_Schema_10-19-2013.png) with the table `node_body` and `body_value` (and `body_summary`) field... So my problems are: 1) this model is stable to Drupal8?  2) how to analyse the impact of change `longtext` datatype to `xml` datatype?  (I can use a postgreSQL trigger for cast bad HTML to XHTML in insert and update operations, but need also to cast to `::text` a lot of `body_value` users...

Comment: Ok, from your comment it looks like you need to store a single field value as a special column type using the standard SQL field storage. I'm not sure Drupal allow arbitrary datatype for column, but if it does you can implement a custom field type (see `hook_field_info()`) with its own schema (see `hook_field_schema()`).